# How can I prevent Chrome from offsetting newly opened Window?

Tags: google-chrome

When I open a new Window in Chrome on Windows 7 (by pressing CTRL+N), the new window does not exactly overlap the existing window.

Instead it is offset to the right slightly.

So, immediately after opening a new window I have to manually move it to the left so that it uses the full screen real estate.

Is there a way to prevent this offset?

Comment: Did you mean a new **window**?

Comment: When I press CTRL+N the new window or tab that opens up says "New tab" at the top. On Firefox I think it's called a "new window" - on Chrome it seems to be called a "new tab".

Comment: It says "new tab" because the new window opens with a new tab, since it doesn't have anything else to display. Here are the [commands from OS X](http://grab.by/grabs/894e675ae84b0306262dac18947475e6.png).

Comment: You're correct. Thanks. I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default way.

The incremental offset is part of Windows (it always puts new non-maximized windows a little down and to the right of the last one until it reaches a threshold and then starts back up, from the top-left again.

Further, the window-position settings that Chrome stores in the Preferences file only get used when you launch Chrome, not for new windows.

You have two options at this point.

1. Submit [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) to request that it be implemented (it could take a while, if it at all)
2. Request somebody to write an extension to do it (it *should* be possible), or write one yourself

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a Windows built-in behavior. If you try this in Windows Explorer, the offset is a different amount than in Chrome. Or if you shift-click Microsoft Paint, it opens the new instance with no offset. Firefox opens new offset windows context dependent. For example, down and to the left if the window is at the top right of the screen.

Comment: Submitted [new issue for this.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1212685)

Answer (score 1):

Not really a Chrome "hack", but here are a few solutions:

- You could use Windows 7's Aero Snap - just pull the new Window up to the top so it gets maximized.
- Double click the new windows's top border  for it to become maximized.
- Or you could press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> right after opening the new window. This will maximize it too.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't currently support this. Add your vote to [the Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1212685).

In the meantime, use this Autohotkey script to accomplish the task.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
$^n::
h:="ahk_id " WinExist("a")
WinGetPos, X, Y,,,A
Send ^n
sleep, 250
WinWaitNotActive, %h%
WinMove, A,, X, Y
Return
#IfWinActive
```